# Changing Newsletter Subscribe Success Email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, newsletter

How do I change the email in the Newsletter Subscribe Success Email? The one on the `from` on the email being received. I would also like to change  the "Newsletter success subscription" text. Is that possible?

Refer to the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "store emails" configuration in System -> Configuration.